# OAuth Flow required every day. Otherwise Callout fails with 401

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider, open-id-connect

In a customer org, Api calls are made using a `NamedCredential` using an `OpenIdConnect` `AuthProvider`. I didn't configure this but my own code fails with 401 Unauthorized. When I going to the NamedCredential and trigger the Auth Flow again it works.

I'm an Oauth newbie but I thought after this initial Authorization when the `NamedCredential` is saved the token is useable for all time.

Is there something configured incorrectly in Salesforce or in the API backend? Any tips and recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Did you include refresh_token as a scope for OAuth? The access tokens generally expire after a few hours. The refresh token allows the system to request a fresh access token without prompting the user again. [What is refresh token](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/)

Comment: Yes the scope is api refresh_token

Comment: The devil is in the details here, it depends on the config and if the response from the other party has correct codes, etc.